# Add to cart without reloading the page in Django with fetch()

Tags: django, fetch-api

i'm currently working in a e-commerce project with django in the backend. I have an "add to cart" functionality already implemented, but as I have it right now it reloads the page every time I add/delete/clear a product to the shopping cart. I'd like to make this without reloading the page.

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def shopping_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = request.user.customer
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        product_id, action = data['product_id'], data['action']
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, completed=False)
        product_order, created = ProductOrder.objects.get_or_create(
            order=order, product=product)

        #  It checks if it is the first time that the product is added to
        #  the shopping cart and sends a messsage
        if created:
            sweetify.success(request, 'Product added to the cart', timer=2000)


#  Checks the button that was clicked (add, remove or clear)

        #  If the action is add checks if there is enough stock of the
        #  product, otherwise sends a message of not enough stock
        if action == 'add':
            if product_order.quantity == product.stock:
                sweetify.warning(
                    request, 'Maximum products available!', timer=2000)
            else:
                product_order.quantity = product_order.quantity + 1
                product_order.save()

        #  If the action is remove it removes 1 product from the total
        #  in the shopping cart
        if action == 'remove':
            product_order.quantity = product_order.quantity - 1
            product_order.save()

        #  If the action is clear it removes all individual products
        #  from the shopping cart
        if action == 'clear':
            print('clear')
            product_order.delete()

        #  It checks if the quantity of the product is zero, and if it
        #  is zero then the product is removed from the shopping cart
        if product_order.quantity <= 0:
            product_order.delete()

        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, completed=False)
        products = list(order.productorder_set.all())

        print(order, products)
        context = {'products': products, 'order': order}
        return render(request, 'store/shopping-cart.html', context)
```

shopping-cart.js file:

```
const updateBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

getBtnValues(updateBtn)
function getBtnValues(btn) {
     for (let index = 0; index < btn.length; index++) {
        btn[index].addEventListener('click', function(){
            const product = this.dataset.product
            const action = this.dataset.action
            updateUserOrder(product, action)
        })
    }    
}

function updateUserOrder(product_id, action){
    console.log('Sending data...')

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/store/cart/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'product_id': product_id,
            'action': action,
        })
    })

    .then ((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })

    .then((data) => {
        location.reload()
    })
}
```

shopping-cart.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h4>Your shopping cart</h4>
        <span>Total products: {{order.get_total_products}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-success table-striped table-hover table-borderless">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="shopping-cart-products">
                {% for item in products %}
                <tr>
                    <td><strong><a href="{% url 'product-detail' item.product.id %}">{{item.product.name}}</a></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td><img src="{{ item.product.image.url }}" alt="" height="50px" width="50px"></td>
                    <td>${{item.product.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td><strong>${{item.get_total_price}}</strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="add"
                                class="btn btn-success card-link update-cart"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"
                                    style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
                            <button data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="remove"
                                class="btn btn-danger card-link update-cart"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus"
                                    style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
                            <button data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="clear"
                                class="btn btn-warning card-link update-cart"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"
                                    style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>

        </table>



    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        {% if order.get_total_products > 0 %}
        <div class="card grey lighten-2" style="height: 100%;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span class="card-title">
                    <h4>Total order price: ${{order.get_order_price}}</h4>
                </span>
                <hr>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Go to the checkout page to complete your purchase
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="{% url 'checkout' order.id%}">
                    <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"
                        class="btn btn-success card-link update-cart">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-credit-card fa-lg" style="color: #ffffff;">
                        </i> Checkout
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock main %}
```

How could I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: It would probably be frontend issue nothing to do with django.

Comment: you need to probably put an ajax call here on the buttons for add to cart, etc.